# Why Won't My Light Instances Stick To Their Parent Vertices?

Tags: modeling

I have a light parented to a plane with four vertices (with Instancing on the Plane set to Vertices).  The light and the plane both have an origin of 0,0,0.

So far so good.  But when I rotate the plane the lights slip out of alignment with the vertices they are attached to.

What am I missing here?

[Project File](https://www.dropbox.com/s/986qc6s0x6rsnxk/Light%20Parenting%20why.blend?dl=0)

This is how it looks when I set it up (Lights in Yellow, Vertices in Red, all properly aligned):

[image: 1]

This is what happens when I rotate:
[image: 2]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have not correctly parented, you've just parented to one vertex, I suppose that what you want is to make a parent to the whole object, so <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>P</kbd> to clear parent, shift select the 4 vertex object, and parent again with a simple <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>P</kbd> this time.

Comment: Actually, OP has _both_  parented to a vertex, _and_ instanced on points. One or the other. The instancing remains, with your answer. Congratulations on deciphering the layout :D

Comment: I'm not sure what he tried to do with a parent to vertex, it can't work

Comment: Hey @moonboots thanks for this.  Strangely your method is exactly what I thought I did the first try but it didn't work, so I read that you have to do a parent to vertex.  But I just tried it again and it worked so I must have done something wrong the first time.  Thanks for clearing this up for me.